# How should I show large data in a text field in android app without using "..." or "Read More"

Tags: android, user-interface

I am developing an app, in which I have to log tasks. the problem is that showing task with large data disrupts UI. The already present solution is  using "..." and when the user clicks on the dots, then a new screen will come out all the data. but I don't want to use it. The other option is using "v" arrow and when user touches it then the field enlarges. Is there any other solution other than these two. the more preferable will be to display the text on the same page.

Comment: You can use textarea inside scrollview.

Comment: Thanks a lot...if you can give an example of any app with this view then that will be really helpful

Comment: Check my answer, you can add as many textviews you want inside scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

**USe this:-**

```
<ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCCDDDDDDDDD" />
        </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks....do you have any app example where these implementations are given. I just want to view it first

Answer (score 0):

According to me u have 2 options :-

1. ScrollView with textView inside it .
2. Horizontal Scroll View with arrows on left and right as slider effect where u can create
   and add textview dynamically with 100 words in each so if u have 1000 words then 10 
   children in textview and it wud be amazing for the user to swipe and see the text then it
   depends upon u wat animation u give.

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ScrollView   
 android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"  
 android:layout_height="1fill_parent"   
 android:layout_width="fill_parent">  

<TextView   
 android:id="@+id/TEXT_VIEW1"   
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
 android:text="This is text view This is text view This is text view This is text view This is text view This is text view This is text view This is text view This is text view This is text view This is text view This is text view This is text view This is text view This is text view" />  

 <TextView   
  android:id="@+id/TEXT_VIEW2"   
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
  android:text="This is text view This is text view This is text view This is text view This is text view This is text view This is text view This is text view This is text view This is text view This is text view This is text view This is text view This is text view This is text view" /> 

</ScrollView>  
</LinearLayout>
```